# Cannot delete Active Directory user

Tags: active-directory

i have a user in Active Directory that i cannot delete:

If i try to delete:

[image]

i get the error:

[image]

If i try to **rename** the user, i get the error:

[image]

If i try to view **Properties** of the user, i get the error:

[image]

What's up with that?

Comment: That doesn't look like a user.  What's the `objectClass`?

Comment: Do you have more than one domain controller (DC)?

Comment: Do you have more than one DC? If so, connect ADUC to another DC and see what state the object is in (if it exists). If the object is editable/deleteable (is that a word?) from another DC, or if it doesn't exist on another DC then you've got a replication problem. You can check the state of replication from a command prompt on each DC by running repadmin/showrepl.

Comment: @ShaneMadden: I suspect that he can't query the `objectClass`. This has the look of a replication conflict resolution but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i managed to delete the user by creating a folder, and moving the mangled user into it - then deleting the folder.

Then i re-created `Forest Gump`.

Still, and actual solution would have been helpful.

- the event log does not have any synchronization errors
- there is a backup DC; this was on the primary

Comment: There are no "backup" and "primary" Domain Controller (DC) computers in Active Directory. All the copies of the database are equal peers.

Comment: *All copies of the database are equal, but some are more equal than others.* As administrators administrating a domain we have chosen to only ever interact with one server - we think of, and use it as, a *primary* server. If that database replicates to another server, and that other server handles requests: so be it.

Answer (score 2):

Check Event Log for errors in Domain Controllers synchronisation (if you have more than one DC) or any other errors related to Directory Services.

Also you can check the integrity of the Active Directory database using ntdsutil.exe tool (ntdsutil files integrity) and/or semantic database analysis (ntdsutil "sem d a" go)